# How can I make a error message when there's no mention on discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to do a error message when a member puts a text instead of a mention, but I can´t.

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, you should specify a user!")

@bot.command(name="kiss")
async def kiss(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    if ctx.message.channel.is_nsfw() :
        with open ('kiss.json') as kg:
            kissgifs = json.load(kg)
        ksrandomchoice = random.choice(kissgifs)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Hi")
        embed.set_image(url=ksrandomchoice['kiss'])
        embed.add_field(name=f"{ctx.author.name} kissed {member.display_name}, that's romantic! ❤️", value="")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

As you can see, for example if I send a message that says "!-kiss", the bot responds "{ctx.author.mention}, you should specify a user!", that's the expected result. But if I put "!-kiss randomtext", the boy says nothing. How can I change that?

I tried to use if and else, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you typehint the parameter `member` with `discord.Member`, you can use either the name, the ID or the mention to get the `discord.Member` object.

Because you can't specify if the user got mentioned via `discord.Member`, you have to do this via `ctx`, like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def kiss(ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member = None):
    # Check if member isn't given
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, you should specify a user!")
        return

    # Check if the given user isn't mentioned
    if member not in ctx.message.mentions:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, you should mention the user!")
        return

    await ctx.send(f"Kiss {member.mention}")
```

Notice the `None` as the default value, to prevent a `MissingRequiredArgument` error if `member` isn't given.

To catch the error, when the user can't be found, you need to use the `on_command_error` event like that:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx: commands.Context, error: commands.CommandError):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MemberNotFound):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, I can't find this user!")
    else:
        raise error
```

**Note:** This event applies globally. Also, you should `raise` the error, if you don't handle it, **otherwise, you won't notice other errors, when one is raised.**

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if isinstance(error, ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, you should specify a user!")
```

to

```
if isinstance(error, ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, you should specify a user!")
```

Since you don't want to check if there's a missing argument you wanna check if its a valid member.